# Symfony redirect(reload) to another page after success

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have ajax call and after call, when success I need redirect(reload) to another cation, example `/test`, how to do it ?

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/app_dev.php/api/tasks',
        data: {
            ids: result,
            invoice_id: invoice_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // how to reload page in another path, example /app_dev.php/test
        },
        error: function () {
            // alert('it broke');
        },
        complete: function () {
            // alert('it completed');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/app_dev.php/api/tasks',
    data: {
        ids: result,
        invoice_id: invoice_id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        location.href = '/app_dev.php/test';
    },
    error: function () {
        // alert('it broke');
    },
    complete: function () {
        // alert('it completed');
    }
});
```

Also for better routing in JS you can look at [FOSJsRoutingBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)

Comment: not understand where need set routing in custom js ?`Routing.generate('route_name', /* your params */)`

Comment: According to the documentation you should set name for your route and provide route's options ({"expose"=true}). After that you will be able to use this route in JS (Routing.generate('route_name', /* your params */))

Answer (score 2):

You can use smyfony2 routing in javascript with **[FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)**

Steps;

1. Install FOSJsRoutingBundle with https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html
2. Use your routings in your success function with https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

For example in your case;

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/app_dev.php/api/tasks',
        data: {
            ids: result,
            invoice_id: invoice_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.document.location = Routing.generate('your_test_route_name');
        },
        error: function () {
            // alert('it broke');
        },
        complete: function () {
            // alert('it completed');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this javascript code to direct the user to another page on success: `window.document.location = '/app_dev.php/test';`.

In your code:

```
success: function (data) {
        // how to reload page in another path, example /app_dev.php/test
        window.document.location = '/app_dev.php/test';
    },
```

> Having said that, you should not hard-code the `'app_dev.php'` part of the url, as you probably already know, since this only works for the dev environment of Symfony.
>
> You can define the 'prefix' web path based on whether the environment is set to 'prod' or 'dev' (or some other environment).

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect from controller via ajax request, so you need to pass redirect path to the response and then

```
success: function(response) {
    window.location.href = response.yourPath;
}
```